# Terraform ip range

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm in the process of trying to create a list of ip's using a combination of a for loop and the range function. I'm trying to get the loop to iterate through the range of numbers and appending that number as the last digits in an ip address.

```
locals {
  windows_ip_list = [for i in range(var.Number) : format("%s%02d", "10.16.0.1", i)]
}
```

Giving the variable var.Number a value of 5 creates a 5 element tuple but the following error is probvided.

```
│    9:   private_ip = local.windows_ip_list  #var.win_ip[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.windows_ip_list is tuple with 5 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "private_ip": string required.
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "Windows" {
  ami = "ami-02c1f4de3809f0050"
  instance_type   = "t2.large"
  #subnet_id       = aws_subnet.Engineering[count.index].id 
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.windows.id 
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.Engineering.id]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.ENG-DEV.id
  count    = var.Number
  private_ip = local.windows_ip_list  #var.win_ip[count.index]
  associate_public_ip_address = false
```

Any help creating the desired list would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `for_each`? Where is your resource code?

Comment: Not using for_each as yet no. Added resource code as requested

Comment: The goal is to assign multiple public IPs to a single ec2 instance?

Comment: The goal is to have multiple instance to the value of var.Number each with an allocated ip that has been created automatically. Trying to avoid creating a large list of ip's and using the count function to iterate through. Its time consuming and not very efficient.

Comment: How frustrating I edited the line private ip's to append with [count.index] and it works. Excellent work many thanks for all your help and quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference the index of the private ip in the windows_ip_list tuple with `local.windows_ip_list[count.index]` instead of `local.windows_ip_list`as the private_ip attribute require a string value not a list

to have a clear view try to echo the values that `local.windows_ip_list` contains by :

```
terraform console
```

then type `local.windows_ip_list` and press enter

Answer (score 1):

Calling the variable and using the count.index was how it was fixed.

```
private_ip = local.windows_ip_list[count.index]
```